# Python plot median value

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, time-series

I am new to Numpy and matplotlib.

I have some data that I want to plot against dates and I would like to only plot out the median value for each date. The number of data points for each date is different.

I have created a 2-D numpy array like this:

```
[[date1, v1], [date1, v2], [date2, v3], [date3, v4], [date3, v5], [date3, v6]]
```

etc....

Now I am lost. How do I plot the daily median?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For time series I would strongly suggest to use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) which is based on `numpy`.

It has some convenience methods to deal with problems like yours.

```
In [5]: import pandas as pd

# generate some data
In [6]: idx = pd.date_range('2013-01-01', pd.datetime.today(), freq='H')

In [7]: s = pd.Series(np.random.random_sample(idx.size) * 1000, index=idx)

In [8]: s.describe() # print some statistics 
Out[8]: 
count    1184.000000
mean      499.817905
std       291.446537
min         0.292728
25%       252.537037
50%       485.828521
75%       758.535148
max       999.681320

In [9]: s.index
Out[9]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-01-01 00:00:00, ..., 2013-02-19 07:00:00]
Length: 1184, Freq: H, Timezone: None

# downsample to daily using median value for a day and plot it
In [10]: s.resample('D', how='median').plot()
Out[10]: <matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot at 0x3d88ad0>
```

[image: pandas_example]

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. I found a way to plot my data, but this is much simpler and cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

for median, just use numpy.median:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.median.html

For dates, look at the matplotlib dates documentation:

http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html

Here's a simple dates demo that might help you:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_demo.html

If you still are stuck after looking at these, try posting some of your code or asking a more specific question.